# How to connect to a remote server and run some code on that particular server?

Tags: linux, shell, script, remote

I am implementing an automated backup scheme so I created a shell script which first creates SQL dumps for all MySQL databases, then retrieves all websites from the `/var/www` directory of a remote server. The latter is working as I am using rsync to get the remote files.

However, the MySQL dumps being retrieved are the ones from the local server which is not what I want. I want to get the SQL dumps from the remote server as well.

I have a tunnel between the local and remote server which I can connect to without using any password (I added the public key to the authorized_hosts), so I tried to add the following code to the script:

```
ssh user@192.168.x.xxx
```

I then attempted to retrieve the SQL dumps and exited from the remote server. However this does not work as I still have to enter exit manually in the terminal for the SQL dumps to be retrieved from the remote host. I don't know why this is happening. This is what the script is trying to do:

```
//connect to remote server 
ssh user@192.168.x.xxx

//retrieve SQL dumps 
//code to retrieve...

//exit from remote server 
exit

//use rsync to get remote files of /var/www from local server (working)
```

Is there a way to connect to the remote host AND run the script's code on THAT remote host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the command you want to run to the end of the ssh command line. So something like this:

```
ssh user@192.168.x.xxx /path/to/script
```

will run `/path/to/script` on the remote machine.

Comment: So simple! yet I couldn't find it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If it's one command, use `ssh user@host remotecommand`. For example:

```
ssh user@dbhost "mysqldump" > dumpfile
```

Note that redirections take place locally (unless you put them inside quotes), so `dumpfile` will be created on the local computer.

The *remotecommand* argument is in fact passed to the default shell of `user`, so you can use stuff like `a; b && c` and if/while statements. But it's wiser to put them in a second script file instead (in the db server).